# Implement Bar code scanner in salesfore1

Tags: salesforce

We have a requirement to develop functionality in salesforce1 so that we can scan the Barcode and store the value in Custom field .

We tried couple of approaches but it is not working . Please help If anyone has implemented something like this .

Thanks in advance !!

Comment: You should share the code of the approaches you tried if you want some help with it.

Answer (score 0):

The following link has the implementation of scanning qr code in salesforce1. 
http://bobbuzzard.blogspot.co.uk/2014/02/reading-qr-codes-in-salesforce1.html

Comment: Hi ,

We have implemented the below link but it is very slow in Salesforce1.ALso it fails for many types of Barcodes.   We tried for jQuery Plugins but that is also not working . 
http://bobbuzzard.blogspot.co.uk/2014/02/reading-qr-codes-in-salesforce1.html